# Moved asp.net site to new server, getting "Key not valid for use in specified state." error

Tags: asp.net, encryption, cryptography

I have set up a brand new, clean server to run our asp.net 4 website on. I have copied over the wwwroot folder from one of the existing servers, imported the configuration, and imported pfx file from the "old" server.

Our website contains a shopping cart and during the payment portion of the cart process on this new server it throws the following error:

```
[CryptographicException: Key not valid for use in specified state.]

   System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope) +374
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedKey.Unprotect() +15
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricCryptographer.Decrypt(Byte[] encryptedText) +66
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithmProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] ciphertext) +187
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.Cryptographer.DecryptSymmetric(String symmetricInstance, Byte[] ciphertext) +114
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.Cryptographer.DecryptSymmetric(String symmetricInstance, String ciphertextBase64) +73
   CompanyName.Objects.BasePayment.get_PaymentNumberLastFour() +17

[TargetInvocationException: Property accessor 'PaymentNumberLastFour' on object 

'CompanyName.Objects.Payment' threw the following exception:'Key not valid for use in specified state.
```

The code has not changed, its the same code on the other web server so I'm assuming it has something to do with the machinekeys. I have tried removing the rsa keys from the application data folder but to no avail.  I'm not very familiar with cryptography in asp.net so its probably something I'm missing.

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered here? http://forums.asp.net/p/1445940/3289695.aspx mirror link to the blog in case that website will be down: http://understandavinash.blogspot.com/2009/03/keysetnotfoundoracessdenied.html

Comment: A couple google links suggest that this error can be cause by passing too many bytes to the Encrypt method. I'd guess that's not the case here, but could it be that your testing on the new server was a false positive?

Comment: I wouldnt think the length would be the problem as it isnt a problem on the old ones.  I did try the first solution to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Typically with the encryption process, there is something machine based that makes the key only work on the machine that generated it, even if you are using some kind of third party provider or key.

Try using the following [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx#paght000006_webfarmscenarios) to export and regenerate the key on your new server.

Comment: I think this is in the right direction.  The web.config does contain a reference to a sym.key located on the c:\ drive of the hosts. I'm wondering if maybe I need to import that into asp.net using "aspnet_regiis -pi "CustomKeys" "C:\CustomKeys.xml" ?

Comment: you may also need to move the machine key located here:  C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have to resign your key used for encrypting CC info.